# New ID column depending on another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, seurat

I want to generate a new ID column in my df based on another column
my df looks something like this

```
> TCR <- c("CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF","CGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF","CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGT", "CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF")
> df <- as.data.frame(TCR)
> df
    cdr3
1 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF
2      CGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF
3 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGT
4 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF
```

I want to add a new column df$ID that looks into df$cdr3 and assigns a new character for each value, and if the value is repeated it uses the same value that was used before
So it becomes something like this

```
>df 
    cdr3                           ID
1 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF     X1 
2      CGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF     X2
3 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGT            X3
4 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF     X1
```

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` in `base R` to match the `unique` values in 'cdr3', get the index and `paste` with `X`

```
df$ID <- paste0("X", match(df$cdr3, unique(df$cdr3)))
```

-output

```
> df
                          cdr3 ID
1 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF X1
2      CGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF X2
3        CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGT X3
4 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF X1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is `tidyverse` solution with using `fct_inorder` from `forcats` package. With `fct_inorder` we could keep ther order in `row_number()`!

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(cdr3) %>% 
  mutate(cdr3 = fct_inorder(cdr3, row_number())) %>% 
  mutate(ID = paste0("X", as.numeric(factor(cdr3))))
```

```
  cdr3                         ID   
  <ord>                        <chr>
1 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF X1   
2 CGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF      X2   
3 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGT        X3   
4 CAAETSGSRLTF;CASSQEGTGVYEQYF X1   
Warning messages:
1: Problem while computing `cdr3 =
fct_inorder(cdr3, row_number())`.
i the condition has length > 1 and only the
  first element will be used 
2: Problem while computing `cdr3 =
fct_inorder(cdr3, row_number())`.
i the condition has length > 1 and only the
  first element will be used
```